# What is the origin of word endings like -ducir, -vocar, -locar, -ludir, -mitir?

Tags: etimología, gramática, historia, morfología, sufijos

The word-endings -ducir, -locar, -vocar, -ludir, -mitir are quite common, each can take a lot of common prefixes to form real words, for example:

- conducir, producir, introducir, aducir, inducir, reducir, seducir, deducir
- invocar, evocar, equivocar, provocar, convocar, revocar
- colocar, dislocar
- aludir, eludir
- admitir, permitir, submitir, transmitir

Is there an original meaning (maybe in latin) of these word-endings?

Answer (score 8):

All those word-roots have Latin origins as follows:

- duco : I lead
- voco : I call
- loco : I place
- ludo : I play
- mitto : I send

Since most of those words have English cognates, I point you to the Internet Wayback Machine's [link to the American Heritage Dictionary](http://web.archive.org/web/20071213145958/http://www.bartleby.com/61/s0.html), which used to be free online, and had good etymologies.